# Always unlink() the POSIX named semaphore in shared memory

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads, ipc, semaphore

In the following code, each thread runs `sell_tickets()` function, takes the mutex lock and decrement the tickets number. In order to limit the active threads number, the `checkin()` and `checkout()` threads is a producer-consumer model using semaphore.

But in the unit-test, it seems that consumer function `checkout()` calls `pthread_join()` function before the producer `checkin()` even creating new threads. So anything wrong? Is it because threads don't share the stack memory segment, since I didn't `malloc()` heap space for some parameters.

```c
/**
 * Using semaphore to limit maximum thread number.
 */
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

/**
 * If arguments that pthread_create() pass to sell_tickets() are more than one, 
 * they need to be wrapped into a single structure.
 */
typedef struct {
    unsigned agent_id;              // simulate an agent
    unsigned tickets_tosell;        // agent's personal goal of the day
    pthread_mutex_t *pool_lock;     // mutex lock for visiting the shared tickets pool
    unsigned *tickets_pool;         // shared tickets pool
} agent;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
static void new_agent(agent *a, unsigned agentid, unsigned ticketsnum, pthread_mutex_t *lock, unsigned *tickets_pool) {
    a->agent_id = agentid;
    a->tickets_tosell = ticketsnum;
    a->pool_lock = lock;
    a->tickets_pool = tickets_pool;
}

/**
 * Implement void *(*start_rtn)(void *);
 * -------------------------------------
 * Each thread execute this function.
 */
static void *sell_tickets(void *agent_addr) {
    agent *a = (agent *)agent_addr;
    while (a->tickets_tosell > 0) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(a->pool_lock);
        (*a->tickets_pool)--;
        printf("agent@%d sells a ticket, %d tickets left in pool.\n", a->agent_id, *a->tickets_pool);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(a->pool_lock);
        a->tickets_tosell--;
        printf("agent@%d has %d tickets to sell.\n", a->agent_id, a->tickets_tosell);
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)&a->agent_id); 
}

typedef struct {
    /* shared threads pool */
    pthread_t *pool_addr;
    unsigned pool_size;
    /* a pair of producer-consumer semaphore */
    sem_t *producer_sem;
    sem_t *consumer_sem;
    /* producer & consumer thread id */
    pthread_t *producer_tid;
    pthread_t *consumer_tid;
} threads_pool;

static void new_threads_pool(threads_pool *tp, 
                        pthread_t *pool_addr, unsigned pool_size, 
                        sem_t *producer_sem, sem_t *consumer_sem, 
                        pthread_t *ptid, pthread_t *ctid) {
    tp->pool_addr = pool_addr;
    tp->pool_size = pool_size;
    tp->producer_sem = producer_sem;
    tp->consumer_sem = consumer_sem;
    tp->producer_tid = ptid;
    tp->consumer_tid = ctid;
}

typedef struct {
    sem_t *checkin_b;
    sem_t *checkout_b;
} barrier;

static void new_barrier(barrier *b, sem_t *inb, sem_t *outb) {
    b->checkin_b = inb;
    b->checkout_b = outb;   
}

typedef struct {
    unsigned num_agents;
    unsigned num_tickets;
} project;

static void new_project(project *p, unsigned num_agents, unsigned num_tickets) {
    p->num_agents = num_agents;
    p->num_tickets = num_tickets;
}

typedef struct {
    project *pj;
    threads_pool *tp;
    barrier *b;
} project_params;

static void new_project_params(project_params *pp, project *pj, threads_pool *tp, barrier *b) {
    pp->pj = pj;
    pp->tp = tp;
    pp->b = b;
}

/**
 * producer thread
 * create agent sell_tickets() threads
 */
static void *checkin(void *params) {
    project_params *pp = (project_params *)params;

    /* barrier assure that checkin() and checkout() thread begin to work when two threads are both created. */
    sem_post(pp->b->checkout_b);
    sem_wait(pp->b->checkin_b);

    unsigned tickets_pool = pp->pj->num_tickets;    // shared resourses
    pthread_mutex_t tickets_pool_lock;              // mutex object

    agent agents[pp->pj->num_agents];               // arguments pass to 10 threads
    unsigned id;                                    // agent id
    pthread_t tid;                                  // current sell_tickets() thread id
    int err;                                        // thread_create() function return the error code

    pthread_mutex_init(&tickets_pool_lock, NULL);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < pp->pj->num_agents; i++) {
        id = i + 1;
        new_agent(&agents[i], id, pp->pj->num_tickets / pp->pj->num_agents, &tickets_pool_lock, &tickets_pool);

        sem_wait(pp->tp->producer_sem);
        err = pthread_create(pp->tp->pool_addr + (i % pp->tp->pool_size), NULL, sell_tickets, &agents[i]);
        if (err != 0) {
            printf("error[%d]: can't create thread.", err);     
            pthread_cancel(*pp->tp->consumer_tid);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        } else {
            tid = *(pp->tp->pool_addr + (i % pp->tp->pool_size));
            printf("thread of agent@%d created, thread id = @%lx\n", id, (unsigned long)tid);
            sem_post(pp->tp->consumer_sem);
        }
    }

    /* wait for checkout() thread to finish */
    pthread_join(*pp->tp->consumer_tid, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&tickets_pool_lock);
    if (tickets_pool == 0) {
        printf("Today's tickets are sold out!\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d tickets left at the end of the day!\n", tickets_pool);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * consumer thread
 * wait for old agent sell_tickets() thread to exit and increment the producer semaphore
 */
static void *checkout(void *params) {
    project_params *pp = (project_params *)params;

    /* barrier assure that checkin() and checkout() thread begin to work when two threads are both created. */
    sem_post(pp->b->checkin_b);
    sem_wait(pp->b->checkout_b);

    void *tret;     // to store pthread_exit() exit status rval_ptr
    int errcode;    // pthread_join() return err code

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < pp->pj->num_agents; i++) {
        sem_wait(pp->tp->consumer_sem);
        errcode = pthread_join(*(pp->tp->pool_addr + (i % pp->tp->pool_size)), &tret);
        sem_post(pp->tp->producer_sem);
        printf("agent@%d has finished his job!\n", *(unsigned *)tret);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * producer-consumer model using semaphore
 * maximum 10 agent sell_tickets() threads work at a time
 */
static void run(void) {
    unsigned num_agents = 30;
    unsigned num_tickets = 300;
    /*
     * project
     */
    project pj;
    new_project(&pj, num_agents, num_tickets);

    /*
     * thread pool of maximum 10 thread 
     */
    unsigned threads_pool_size = 10;
    pthread_t pool[threads_pool_size];

    /* 
     * checkin() and checkout() threads
     */
    pthread_t checkin_tid, checkout_tid;
    int checkin_err, checkout_err;
    /* a pair of producer-consumer semaphores */
    sem_t *checkin_sem, *checkout_sem;
    checkin_sem = sem_open("/checkin_sem", O_CREAT, S_IRWXG, threads_pool_size);
    checkout_sem = sem_open("/checkout_sem", O_CREAT, S_IRWXG, 0);
    /* barrier */
    barrier b;
    sem_t *checkin_b, *checkout_b;
    checkin_b = sem_open("/checkin_b", O_CREAT, S_IRWXG, 0);
    checkout_b = sem_open("/checkout_b", O_CREAT, S_IRWXG, 0);
    new_barrier(&b, checkin_b, checkout_b);
    /* wrap checkin() checkout() parameters into a single structure */
    threads_pool tp;
    new_threads_pool(&tp, &pool[0], threads_pool_size, checkin_sem, checkout_sem, &checkin_tid, &checkout_tid);
    project_params pp;
    new_project_params(&pp, &pj, &tp, &b);
    /* create checkin(), checkout() threads */
    checkin_err = pthread_create(&checkin_tid, NULL, checkin, &pp);
    checkout_err = pthread_create(&checkout_tid, NULL, checkout, &pp);
    if (checkin_err != 0 || checkout_err != 0) {
        if (checkin_err != 0) printf("error: checkin() thread creation failed!\n");
        if (checkout_err != 0) printf("error: checkout() thread creation failed!\n");
        sem_close(checkin_sem);
        sem_close(checkout_sem);
        sem_close(checkin_b);
        sem_close(checkout_b);
        return;
    }

    /*
     * wait for checkin() and checkout() to exit
     */
    pthread_join(checkin_tid, NULL);
    pthread_join(checkout_tid, NULL);

    /*
     * free resources
     */
    sem_close(checkin_sem);
    sem_close(checkout_sem);
    sem_close(checkin_b);
    sem_close(checkout_b);
}
    

int main(void) {
    run();
}
```

`lldb` shows that `thread_join()` return error code `3`:`ESRCH`.

```
Process 46631 stopped
* thread #3, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003b39 agtktp`checkout(params=0x00007ffeefbff618) at agents_tickets_pool.c:221:46
   217  errcode = pthread_join(*(pp->tp->pool_addr + (i % pp->tp->pool_size)), &tret);
   218  pthread_t tid = *(pp->tp->pool_addr + (i % pp->tp->pool_size));
   219  printf("thread@%u = %lx\n", i + 1, (unsigned long)tid);
   220          sem_post(pp->tp->producer_sem);
-> 221          printf("agent@%d has finished his job!\n", *(unsigned *)tret);
   222      }
   223      pthread_exit(NULL);
   224  }
Target 0: (agtktp) stopped.
(lldb) fr v errcode
(int) errcode = 3
(lldb) fr v tid
(pthread_t) tid = 0x0000000000000050
```

=== 01/03/2021 UPDATE 2 ===

I've posted the solution. Feel free to correct me if something wrong. Thanks everyone, especially @Semion.

=== END 01/03/2021 UPDATE 2 ===

=== 01/03/2021 UPDATE 1 ===

Currently I have fixed the problem, and find out I've made a typical mistake in the following code.

I need some time to re-edit this question and give an answer, to make it useful for later POSIX Semaphore user. Please **DO NOT** close this question (it has already 2 close votes). Thanks.

=== END 01/03/2021 UPDATE 1 ===

Comment: It is nice that you are able to use a debugger. But please note, that Stack Overflow is NOT a *debugging* service. You have an idea, that "it seems that consumer function `checkout()` calls `pthread_join()` function before the producer `checkin()` even creating new threads.". Have you tried to verify that fact? Yes, a multithreaded application has some difficulties when debugged. But `printf()` and `pause()` in a specific thread and specific place still could help.

Comment: We indeed are not a debugging service, though we do sometimes answer debugging questions.  We generally expect such questions to present a [mre], which yours does not.  I have no qualms whatsoever about insisting on an MRE, because constructing one is a powerful debugging technique in its own right.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger , I fully respect the value of MRE and keep doing so. Considering that thread implementation is system dependent, I'm working on mac os, if you test on Linux, I can't promise it's behavior remain strictly the same. Even on my machine with the same code, the thread order always change. That's why concurrent debug is tricky. But still appreciate for your advice.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I believe that your suggestion `Have you tried to verify that fact?` is for good. The fact is before posted this question, I had spent 10+ hours on this bug. The reason why I didn't post the debug snippets (as you mentioned `printf()`, is to keep the code clean and readable. I said "it seems that ... ", it's not a guess, but exactly the test result (the "fact" you said). For `debugging service` problem, I will update the question after solving the problem, to leave a clue to later programmer. Let's keep our community WARM together. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasWenzel , you have the point.

Comment: When I run your code on linux, on the second run and after it crashes on `sem_post(pp->b->checkout_b);` because `sem_open("/checkin_b", O_CREAT, S_IRWXG, 0)` fails. `ls`ing `/dev/shm` shows that semaphores created with `----r-x---`, so they can't be opened again after first run. Changing to `S_IRWXU` and removing the old semaphores solves the problem for me.

Comment: @Semion this gives me some clues, let me recheck on that direction.

Comment: @Semion Could I know if  the program work correctly on your linux after changing to `S_IRWXU`? To simplify the problem I temporarily set permission to `777` using `S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO`, program still block on main thread.

Comment: @Semion after clean the memory, it works well now. Thanks a lot. And I still want to know how did you check the file mode of semaphore?

Comment: In linux the semaphores seemingly also present as files in /dev/shm, so `ls -l /dev/shm` gives a list of them with the file permissions. Glad to hear you've found the bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is fixed now. The problem is in `sem_close()`.

According to *"Unix Networking Program - Vol.2 - ch10"*, `sem_close()` closes a semaphore, but does not remove it from the system shared memory. POSIX named semaphores are "*kernel-persistent*".

So basically I'm using the same pair of old semaphore called `/checkin_sem` and `checkout_sem` for each run. Once the program exit improperly and leave some strange values in the semaphore, all subsequent tests will crash. That's why some others said that the program works well on their machine. Because they have no legacy semaphore on their system.

**To solve this, we should use `sem_unlink()` instead**, with which semaphore name will be removed from system, and the destruction of the semaphore will take place until the last `sem_close()` occurs. Since close operation occurs automatically on process termination, we don't have to write `sem_close()` explicitly.

```c
sem_unlink("/checkin_sem");
sem_unlink("/checkout_sem");
sem_unlink("/checkin_b");
sem_unlink("/checkout_b");
```

And to prevent the legacy semaphore affect our program, it's better to add `O_EXCL` when create the semaphore, which will pop an error when semaphore already exists.

```c
checkin_sem = sem_open("/checkin_sem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE, threads_pool_size);
checkout_sem = sem_open("/checkout_sem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE, 0);
```

At last, for the permission flag, if the program doesn't concern inter-process communication, the simple `read`, `write` for owner is enough, which is `S_IREAD | S_IWRITE` or `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR`.

Here's the final version of this producer-consumer threads pool.

```c
/**
 * Using semaphore to limit maximum thread number.
 */
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * If arguments that pthread_create() pass to sell_tickets() are more than one, 
 * they need to be wrapped into a single structure.
 */
typedef struct {
    unsigned agent_id;              // simulate an agent
    unsigned tickets_tosell;        // agent's personal goal of the day
    unsigned *tickets_pool;         // shared tickets pool
    pthread_mutex_t *pool_lock;     // mutex lock for visiting the shared tickets pool
} agent;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
static void new_agent(agent *a, unsigned agentid, unsigned tickets_num, unsigned *pool, pthread_mutex_t *lock) {
    a->agent_id = agentid;
    a->tickets_tosell = tickets_num;
    a->tickets_pool = pool;
    a->pool_lock = lock;
}

/**
 * Implement void *(*start_rtn)(void *);
 * -------------------------------------
 * Each thread execute this function.
 */
static void *sell_tickets(void *agent_addr) {
    agent *a = (agent *)agent_addr;
    while (a->tickets_tosell > 0) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(a->pool_lock);   // begin of race condition
        (*a->tickets_pool)--;
        fprintf(stdout, "agent@%d sells a ticket, %d tickets left in pool.\n", a->agent_id, *a->tickets_pool);
        fflush(stdout);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(a->pool_lock); // end of race condition
        a->tickets_tosell--;
        fprintf(stdout, "agent@%d has %d tickets to sell.\n", a->agent_id, a->tickets_tosell);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)&a->agent_id); 
}

/**
 * Simulate a tickets selling project
 */
struct {
    unsigned num_agents;
    unsigned num_tickets;
} project;

/**
 * Shared threads pool
 */
struct {
    unsigned pool_size;
    pthread_t *pool;
} threads_pool;

/**
 * Producer, consumer threads id
 */
struct {
    pthread_t producer;
    pthread_t consumer;
} producer_consumer;

/**
 * A pair of semaphore
 */
struct {
    sem_t *producer_sem;
    sem_t *consumer_sem;
} sem;

/**
 * Barrier is not implemented in mac os, we use a pair of semaphore instead.
 */
struct {
    sem_t *producer_b;
    sem_t *consumer_b;
} barrier;

/**
 * producer thread
 * create agent sell_tickets() threads
 */
static void *producer(void *arg) {
    /* barrier assure that checkin() and checkout() thread begin to work when two threads are both created. */
    sem_post(barrier.consumer_b);
    sem_wait(barrier.producer_b);

    unsigned tickets_pool = project.num_tickets;    // shared resource for each agent
    pthread_mutex_t tickets_pool_lock;              // mutex lock for visiting tickets pool

    agent agents[project.num_agents];               // arguments pass to 10 threads
    unsigned id;                                    // agent id
    pthread_t tid;                                  // current sell_tickets() thread id
    int err;                                        // thread_create() return err code

    pthread_mutex_init(&tickets_pool_lock, NULL);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < project.num_agents; i++) {
        id = i + 1;
        new_agent(&agents[i], id, project.num_tickets / project.num_agents, &tickets_pool, &tickets_pool_lock);

        sem_wait(sem.producer_sem);
        err = pthread_create(threads_pool.pool + i % threads_pool.pool_size, NULL, sell_tickets, &agents[i]);
        if (err != 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "error[%d]: can't create thread.\n", err);      
            fflush(stdout);
            pthread_cancel(producer_consumer.consumer);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        } else {
            tid = *(threads_pool.pool + i % threads_pool.pool_size);
            fprintf(stdout, "thread of agent@%d created, thread id = @%lx\n", id, (unsigned long)tid);
            fflush(stdout);
            sem_post(sem.consumer_sem);
        }
    }

    /* wait for checkout() thread to finish */
    pthread_join(producer_consumer.consumer, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&tickets_pool_lock);
    if (tickets_pool == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Today's tickets are sold out!\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d tickets left at the end of the day!\n", tickets_pool);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * consumer thread
 * wait for old agent sell_tickets() thread to exit and increment the producer semaphore
 */
static void *consumer(void *arg) {
    /* barrier assure that checkin() and checkout() thread begin to work when two threads are both created. */
    sem_post(barrier.producer_b);
    sem_wait(barrier.consumer_b);

    void *tret;     // to store pthread_exit() exit status rval_ptr

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < project.num_agents; i++) {
        sem_wait(sem.consumer_sem);
        pthread_join(*(threads_pool.pool + i % threads_pool.pool_size), &tret);
        sem_post(sem.producer_sem);
        fprintf(stdout, "agent@%d has finished his job!\n", *(unsigned *)tret);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * maximum 10 agent sell_tickets() threads work at a time
 */
static void run(void) {
    /* project */
    project.num_agents = 30;
    project.num_tickets = 300;
    /* threads pool */
    threads_pool.pool_size = 10;
    pthread_t pool[threads_pool.pool_size];
    threads_pool.pool = &pool[0];
    /* producer-consumer semaphore */
    sem.producer_sem = sem_open("/producer_sem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE, threads_pool.pool_size);
    sem.consumer_sem = sem_open("/consumer_sem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE, 0);
    /* barrier */
    barrier.producer_b = sem_open("/producer_b", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE, 0);
    barrier.consumer_b = sem_open("/consumer_b", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE, 0);
    /* create producer(), consumer() threads */
    int producer_err = pthread_create(&producer_consumer.producer, NULL, producer, NULL);
    int consumer_err = pthread_create(&producer_consumer.consumer, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    if (producer_err != 0 || consumer_err != 0) {
        if (producer_err != 0) { 
            fprintf(stdout, "error: checkin() thread creation failed!\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        if (consumer_err != 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "error: checkout() thread creation failed!\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        sem_unlink("/producer_sem");
        sem_unlink("/consumer_sem");
        sem_unlink("/producer_b");
        sem_unlink("/consumer_b");
        return;
    }

    /*
     * wait for checkin() and checkout() to exit
     */
    pthread_join(producer_consumer.producer, NULL);
    pthread_join(producer_consumer.consumer, NULL);

    /*
     * free resources
     * --------------
     * Always use sem_unlink() to remove the semaphore, but not sem_close().
     * Close a semaphore does NOT remove the semaphore from system shared memory.
     * Close operation occurs automatically on process termination, we don't have 
     * to write sem_close() explicitly. 
     */
    sem_unlink("/producer_sem");
    sem_unlink("/consumer_sem");
    sem_unlink("/producer_b");
    sem_unlink("/consumer_b");
}
    

int main(void) {
    run();
}
```